# Any one succeed to [clone a Rocky linux 9 disk image and restore to a new machine] by using Clonezilla Live?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, backup, clonezilla

I am trying to backup my Rocky Linux 9 disk image and restore it to an other newer machine with same size SSD by using Clonezilla Live 3.0.3-22.

My Rocky 9 Linux was installed by default partition (divided into 3 partition: sda1 mounted to /boot/efi; sda2 mounted to /boot; sda3 there are 3 logic partitions such as: /, /home and swap)

```
[root@rocky9pg15m ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0 236.9G  0 part 
  ├─rl-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rl-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rl-home 253:2    0 159.1G  0 lvm  /home
```

When I use Clonezilla live to backup it's disk image to my SSH server successfully.(follow instruction of https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image)

But when I tried to restore it to my an other machine (similar hard ware and same disk size) from SSH server.

Restore step as:

```
English UTF-8
Keep default keyboard
Start Clonezilla
device-image
SSH_server ...........
use beginner mode
restoredisk
[restore to local disk] sda 256GB_MT-256
k0 - use the partition table from the image
yes, check the image before restore
[go .......]
```

The new machine only boot to emergency mode.

When I run lsblk I found some thing missing in that table:

```
[root@rocky9pg15m ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0 236.9G  0 part 
  ├─rl-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  └─rl-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

if compare with original partition table, seems logic partition rl-home missed in the restored disk.

if we run command [journalctl -xb], we found there are quite few warning and error message popped up.

```
........
ACPI: NMI not connected to LINT 1!
........
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
........
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
........
device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
........
pmd_set_huge: Cannot satisfy [mem 0xf8000000-0xf8200000] with a huge-page mapping due to MTRR override
........
/dev/sda3 excluded: device is not in devices file
........
warning: no autoactivation for /dev/sda3: system.devices t10_ATA_______[origin disk label]____current t10_ATA_______[new disk label] (??????seems disk label not match???????)
.......
dev-mapper-rl\x2dhome.device: Job dev-mapper-rl\x2dhome.device/start timed out
Timed out waiting for device /dev/mapper/rl-home
........
[other error related to /home]
........ 
Failed to get new runlevel, utmp update skipped.
........
```

Does any one have any idea about it? I mean clone a running Linux system to other new machine by using Clonezilla Live.

If any one do, please advise!

Comment: `logic partition rl-home` you mean the the logical volume rl-home?

Comment: Yeah, rl-home is under partition sda3.

Comment: yes, it's a logical volume, sda3 would be a "Linux LVM" type partition. Anyway, is your clonezilla taking a full (raw) disk image of /dev/sda?

Comment: Not sure, but restore processing not raise error and went to end. One more question, How to check Clonezilla log file to find out what's wrong?

Comment: No idea. How big is the backup file clonezilla creates, and what options did you use in clonezilla to do the backup

Comment: Backup image size is about 1.2GB, not very big.

Comment: you're probably doing it wrong then - but you haven't shown the backup command you used in clonezilla, so, that's just speculation

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,
I have exactly the same problem with the cloning od Rocky Linux 9,2 : whatever the cloning tools used (Clonzilla and dd under linux or Acronis, Aomei backupper under Windows) the result is the same, namely that only maintenance mode is possible when you start on the clone. lsblk on the cloned SSD shows that the /home logical partition is missing while the other two logical partitions swap and / have been copied successfully. If anyone has a clue...thanks in advance

source:

```
[root@mail ~]# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda 8:0 0 111.8G 0 disk
└─sda1 8:1 0 111.8G 0 part /srv/samba/DATA
sdb 8:16 0 119.2G 0 disk
├─sdb1 8:17 0 600M 0 share /boot/efi
├─sdb2 8:18 0 1G 0 part /boot
└─sdb3 8:19 0 117.7G 0 share
   ├─rl-root 253:0 0 70G 0 lvm /
   ├─rl-swap 253:1 0 3.8G 0 lvm [SWAP]
   └─rl-home 253:2 0 43.9G 0 lvm /home
[root@mail~]#

[root@mail ~]# dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda bs=4M conv=sync status=progress
127976603648 bytes (128 GB, 119 GiB) copied, 972 s, 132 MB/s
30526+1 records read
30527+0 records written
128039518208 bytes (128 GB, 119 GiB) copied, 975.921 s, 131 MB/s
the clone gives
[root@mail ~]# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda 8:0 0 111.8G 0 disk
├─sda1 8:1 0 111.8G 0 part /srv/samba/DATA
sdb 8:16 0 119.2G 0 disk
├─sdb1 8:17 0 600M 0 share /boot/efi
├─sdb2 8:18 0 1G 0 part /boot
└─sdb3 8:19 0 117.7G 0 share
   ├─rl-root 253:0 0 70G 0 lvm /
   ├─rl-swap 253:1 0 3.8G 0 lvm [SWAP]
[root@mail~]#
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello,
By searching, because very little documented, I found the solution to the Rocky linux 9.xx cloning problem. Here is the solution that works for me:
1) nano /etc/lvm/devices , add the line to the devices chapter:
                                      use_devicesfile=0
and validate
2) then delete or rename the file /etc/lvm/devices/system.devices
3) Restart and this time Rocky Linux 9.xx launches normally